# Visualize Strongly Connected Components result using Cypher

Tags: apache-spark, neo4j, cypher, strongly-connected-graph, neo4j-mazerunner

I've used [neo4j-mazerunner](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-mazerunner) to analyze **strongly_connected_components** relationship on my graph. The process has ended and now I got the **strongly_connected_components** property on my nodes.

I have used the following query to get rows of nodes distinct nodes:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE has(n.strongly_connected_components)
RETURN DISTINCT "node" as element, n.strongly_connected_components
AS strongly_connected_components
LIMIT 25 UNION ALL MATCH ()-[r]-()
WHERE has(r.strongly_connected_components)
RETURN DISTINCT "relationship" AS element, r.strongly_connected_components 
AS strongly_connected_components LIMIT 25
```

I'm not sure how to cypher query the graph in order to visualize the generated clusters.

Any help would be appericiated.

Comment: You have a few problems in your query, aside from it not doing what you are asking about. `RETURN DISTINCT "node" as element, ...` will always return the string "node" as the value of the `element` column in your results -- this is probably not what you intended. Also, the sub-query after the `UNION` clause should never match anything, since mazerunner only adds the `strongly_connected_components` property to nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should return 25 clusters, and you should be able to visualize each cluster in the browser as strongly connected nodes. The query assumes that `FOO` was the relationship specified to `neo4j-mazerunner` when asking it to generate the `strongly_connected_components` values.

NOTE: Turn OFF the browser's AUTO-COMPLETE feature (in the lower right-hand corner of the result pane) to only see the `FOO` relationships between the nodes in each cluster:

```
MATCH p=(n1)-[:FOO]->()
RETURN n1.strongly_connected_components AS clusterId, COLLECT(p) AS paths
LIMIT 25;
```

Since `neo4j-mazerunner` assigns the same `strongly_connected_components` value to all the nodes in the same cluster, this query simply aggregates all the paths with the same `strongly_connected_components` value (identified as `clusterId`).

Answer (score 1):

you can query a specific id using:

```
match (n2 {strongly_connected_components:NODE_ID_HERE})-[r:NEXT]->(n) return n,n2 LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however I would like to visualize all clusters, and nodes connected to that cluster (limiting results for graphics limitations)

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably misunderstanding the problem here, but this will give you the bigger picture of your strongly connected nodes:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE has(n.strongly_connected_components) MATCH (n)-[*]-() RETURN n
```